# How to find the pdf of the random variable $Z = 9/(X+1)^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $\operatorname{f}_X\left(x\right) = \left(x + 1\right)/4, \,\,0 < x < 2$ and $0$ otherwise:

- How to find the pdf of the random variable $Z = 9/\left(X+1\right)^{2}\ ?$.

Comment: There are several ways of approaching this.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{H}$ is the
$\ds{Heaviside\ Step\ Function}$.
\begin{align}
{\cal P}\pars{z} & = \on{H}\pars{z}\totald{}{z}\int_{0}^{z}{\cal P}\pars{z'}\dd z'
\\[5mm] & =
\on{H}\pars{z}\totald{}{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{f}_{X}\pars{x}
\on{H}\pars{z - {9 \over \bracks{x + 1}^{\,2}}}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\on{H}\pars{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{f}_{X}\pars{x}\,
\delta\pars{z - {9 \over \bracks{x + 1}^{2}}}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\on{H}\pars{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{f}_{X}\pars{x}\,
\bracks{{\delta\pars{x - z_{-}} \over
18/\verts{\pars{1 + z_{-}}^{3}}} +
{\delta\pars{x - z_{+}} \over
18/\verts{\pars{1 + z_{+}}^{3}}}}\dd x
\end{align}
where $\ds{z_{\pm} \equiv {\pm 3 - \root{z} \over \root{z}}}$.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
{\cal P}\pars{z} & =
\on{H}\pars{z}{1 \over 18}
\on{f}_{X}\pars{z_{+}}\verts{\pars{1 + z_{+}}^{3}}
\\[5mm] & =
\on{H}\pars{z}\,{3 \over 2}
\on{f}_{X}\pars{3 - \root{z} \over \root{z}}z^{-3/2}
\\[5mm] & =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{\on{H}\pars{z}{3 \over 2}{\pars{3 - \root{z}}/\root{z} + 1 \over 4}z^{-3/2}} &
\mbox{if} &
\ds{0 < {3 - \root{z} \over \root{z}} < 2}
\\
\ds{0} && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
\implies {\cal P}\pars{z} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{{9 \over 8z^{2}}} & \mbox{if} &
\ds{1 < z < 9}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}}
$$